# Model View Presenter project class gives null value

Tags: c#, mvp, webformsmvp

In my project I created a object and put some values but when those values are saved I don't get same value into my presenter like

I entered these values into my component file

```
SaveOrder abcd = somecomponent.create();
```

in somecomponent.cs file I wrote this method `create()` like

```
public SaveOrder create()
{
    abcd.xyz = new Data.Hibernate.Model.dddd.xyz();

    abcd.xyz .Customer = blahblah;
    abcd.xyz .Device = blahblah;
}
```

and in SaveOrder.cs file I decalared xyz like this

```
  public virtual xyz xyz{ get; set; }
```

and my xyz.cs is like this

```
namespace Myproject.Data.Hibernate.Model.xyz
{
    [Serializable] public class xyz: IEntity, IEquatable<xyz>
    {      
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Other { get; set; }
        public virtual int? Device { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = Id;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Other != null ? Other.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Device.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(xyz other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Id == other.Id 
            && string.Equals(Other, other.Other) 
            && Device == other.Device;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((xyz)obj);
    }      
}
```

My Presenter file is like this

```
namespace Myproject.Business.Presenters.xyz
{
    public abstract class BasexyzTabPresenter<TOrderComponent, TOrder> 
        : BaseTabPresenter<IPageView>
        where TOrderComponent : BaseComponent<TOrder>
        where TOrder : BaseOrder
    {
        private readonly XYZPanel _xyzPanel;

        private readonly TOrder _order;
        private readonly TOrderComponent _orderComponent;
        protected BasexyzTabPresenter
            (TOrderComponent orderComponent, XYZPanel xyzPanel, TOrder order, IPageView view)
            : base(view)
        {
            _xyzPanel = xyzPanel;
            _order = order;
            _orderComponent = orderComponent;
        }
```

In presenter I can't get my xyz.cs file values in `TOrder order`.

EDIT

in SaveOrder.cs public virtual xyz xyz{ get; set; } can't access model when control goes to presenter . That's the main issue here . Please help

Comment: That's a lot of C# version. Is it on purpuse? Are you looking for solution that work one those version?

Comment: thanks for reply . can you tell me how to access model from presenter cause my project is in MVP structure . I'm facing issue like after putting values into model it shows empty in presenter . I meant to say presenter shows null value but I put values into model parameters .